# Moving a window to a specific monitor on Linux

Tags: linux, window-manager, multi-monitor

I am looking for a Linux program that can add an option on each window or a keyboard shortcut that would allow me to move a window to a specified monitor. Free is better.

On Windows, I use [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/), it cannot add a keyboard shortcut but it adds an option in the menu of each window:

[image]

Demo (for whatever reason LICEcap fails to show the icon I am clicking in the recording...):  UltraMon allows me to choose to which monitor the window should be moved amongst all monitors

[image]

Comment: This is typically a window manager feature. What window manager do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which desktop you are using - I use KDE - the icon in the top left of the application window, (with the application icon on it), includes a menu item to allow you to select a specific screen, e.g:

[image: Select Screen Menu]

or to a given, (or all), desktop if you have multiple desktops specified, e.g.:

[image: App Icon Menu][image: select desktop menu]

You can also specify other options such as always on top, etc:

[image: More Options]

Comment: Confirmed for LXDE as well. Looks a little different, but works the same. Even lets you pin a window to be "always on top" (or "always in background").

Comment: I think the OP means the "Move to Screen" option right below the pictured "Move to Desktop", but it works the same way

Comment: Since I have only 2 screens but 6 desktops for me that is the option that I use the most, expanding answer to also show move to screen.